# Select sibling dom element based on the text content of one of sibling

Tags: javascript, html, css, x-ray

I have following html structure -

```
<p>
    <span class="font-weight-medium">
            Phone Number:
    </span>
   <br>
   <span>(123) 456-7869</span>
</p>
```

Now I want to select all such **span** which have **phone number** using pure javascript or css selector. 
I am using **x-ray**.
I had tried this but this doesn't seems to work.

```
  x(html,'span[contains(text(),"Phone Number")]')
  (function(err, obj) {
      console.log(obj);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all `span` elements and loop to find next `span` after those containing `Phone Number`:

```js
span_tags = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i=0, max=span_tags.length; i < max; i++) {
  el =  span_tags[i];
  str = el.innerHTML;
  regex = / *Phone Number: */;
  if ( str.match(regex)) {
    console.log(span_tags[i+1].innerHTML);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="font-weight-medium">
Phone Number:
  </span>
  <span>(123) 456-7869</span>
</p>
```

I'm not sure there is a css selector based solution (`:contain` is a `jquery` pseudo selector). But here is another approach using `indexOf`:

```js
span_tags = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i=0, max=span_tags.length; i < max; i++) {
  if (span_tags[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Phone Number:") != -1) {
   console.log(span_tags[i+1].innerHTML);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="font-weight-medium">
Phone Number:
  </span>
  <span>(123) 456-7869</span>
</p>
```

Comment: That's a perfectly valid answer but is there any css selector based answer without using jquery?

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine using jQuery, then, here is the answer:

```
$("span:contains(Phone Number:)~span")
```

or this

```
$('span:contains(Phone Number:)').siblings('span')
```

Comment: I am not using jquery. But anyway thanks for answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Internally x-ray uses cheerio which is lightweight implementation of jquery. So jquery selectors works in my case! 
I used following - 
`'span:contains(Phone Number:) ~ span'`

If you update your answer then I will mark it accepted.